# How to import and apply a qss file when building 3dsmax plugin

Tags: c++, qt, 3dsmax

I'm building a 3dsmax plugin use VS2015+Qt.I build the plugin with C++ and load a Qt UI when click menu item.But it can't load my qss file and just show a dialog with text and buttons with no stylesheet.I load the qss file by :/prefix/alias.Is there something i did wrong?Thank you for your helping.
  For building details,i use 3dsmaxPluginWizard to generate basic codes,then add some codes to add a new menu to 3dsmax main menubar.Creat my UI by QtCreator and add the cpps,headers and moc files into my project.I think this process should be feasible. 
  My qrc File:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/icons">
        <file alias="btnClose">icons/icon_ close1.png</file>
        <file>icons/icon_ close1@2x.png</file>
        <file alias="btnCloseHover">icons/icon_ close2.png</file>
        <file>icons/icon_ close2@2x.png</file>
        <file alias="btnMini">icons/icon_ mini1.png</file>
        <file>icons/icon_ mini1@2x.png</file>
        <file alias="btnMiniHover">icons/icon_ mini2.png</file>
        <file>icons/icon_ mini2@2x.png</file>
        <file alias="lowerTriangle">icons/icon_callin.png</file>
        <file>icons/icon_callin@2x.png</file>
        <file alias="checkBoxUncheck">icons/icon_choose1.png</file>
        <file>icons/icon_choose1@2x.png</file>
        <file alias="checkBoxChecked">icons/icon_choose2.png</file>
        <file>icons/icon_choose2@2x.png</file>
        <file alias="radioBtnUncheck">icons/icon_choose11.png</file>
        <file>icons/icon_choose11@2x.png</file>
        <file alias="radioBtnChecked">icons/icon_choose22.png</file>
        <file>icons/icon_choose22@2x.png</file>
        <file alias="upperTriangle">icons/icon_down.png</file>
        <file>icons/icon_down@2x.png</file>
        <file alias="infoError">icons/icon_error.png</file>
        <file>icons/icon_error@2x.png</file>
        <file alias="infoFail">icons/icon_fail.png</file>
        <file>icons/icon_fail@2x.png</file>
        <file alias="infoHelp">icons/icon_mark.png</file>
        <file>icons/icon_mark@2x.png</file>
        <file alias="btnOpen1">icons/icon_open1.png</file>
        <file>icons/icon_open1@2x.png</file>
        <file alias="btnOpen2">icons/icon_open2.png</file>
        <file>icons/icon_open2@2x.png</file>
        <file alias="infoRight">icons/icon_right.png</file>
        <file>icons/icon_right@2x.png</file>
        <file alias="btnShut1">icons/icon_shut1.png</file>
        <file>icons/icon_shut1@2x.png</file>
        <file alias="btnShut2">icons/icon_shut2.png</file>
        <file>icons/icon_shut2@2x.png</file>
        <file alias="infoSuccess">icons/icon_succ.png</file>
        <file>icons/icon_succ@2x.png</file>
        <file alias="infoWarning">icons/icon_warn.png</file>
        <file>icons/icon_warn@2x.png</file>
        <file alias="downArrow">icons/icon_down1.png</file>
        <file>icons/icon_down1@2x.png</file>
        <file alias="upArrow">icons/icon_up1.png</file>
        <file>icons/icon_up1@2x.png</file>
    </qresource>
    <qresource prefix="/pic">
        <file alias="banner">pictures/banner.png</file>
        <file>pictures/banner@2x.png</file>
    </qresource>
    <qresource prefix="/qss">
        <file alias="mainQss">styleSheet.qss</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

My qrc import method:

```
bool ret;
QFile qss(":/qss/mainQss");
if (qss.exists() && qss.open(QFile::ReadOnly) && qss.isOpen()) {
    QString qssStr = QLatin1String(qss.readAll());
    qApp->setStyleSheet(qssStr);
    qss.close();
    ret = true;
}
else {
    ret = false;
}
return ret;
```

Comment: Are you compiling a qresource and adding that to your plugin DLL?  Show your QRC file, confirm whether it's being compiled by Qt's resource compiler, and show the code you're using to load the QSS file at runtime.

Comment: Sorry for not providing my codes.At present,i just import my qrc file and set the stylesheet,but i tried to compile my qrc to rcc file and registered it by QResource::registerResource("absolute path of my rcc file"),however,it returns false.

Comment: RCC generates a cpp file from your compiled resource.  Is that cpp file compiled along with the rest of your plugin source?  You ought to be able to simply access it without invoking `registerResource`, because that's handled automatically via static instantiation in the generated cpp.  Other things you could try are not testing `QFile::exists` (I don't in my plugin), or using the relative path (plus prefix, of course) instead of alias: _e.g._ `":/qss/styleSheet.qss"`

Comment: The cpp file is generated automaticlly by QtCreator like qrc_xxx.cpp,not along with other plugin cpps and i didn't add it in my project actually.I added some details after your first comment,is there anything wrong with my build process?

Comment: You say that you are using VS2015 to compile the plugin, not QtCreator.  You should add the cpp file in your VS project if you want access to the resources it was compiled from.

Comment: Maybe something i did wrong,i use VS2015 to compile the plugin,but UI(and moc,ui_xxx.h) is created by QtCreator.After debug that ui,i add all UI files(cpps,headers,moc,) into my VS project.Is there any problem with this method?If that way wrong,maybe i will just ues VS2015

Comment: Personally, I don't use QtCreator so I can't comment.  I have the qrc files as part of my VS project, and have custom build steps for the qrc and the moc.  It might be something else though.  Are you using the exact version of Qt that the MaxSDK is compiled for?  Check the Autodesk developer docs for whichever version of Max you're supporting.  I'm guessing since you're using VS 2015 it's Max 2017, 2018 or 2019.  That's Qt 4.8.5, 5.6.2 and 5.6.3 respectively.

Comment: i use Qt 5.9 while the MaxSDK need 5.6.3,i'll try 5.6.3 later,thanks for your timely assistance